GPU fans are not spinning on 23.10 with fan1_input: Operation not supported
GPU fans on AMD R7 370 video card don't spin on ubuntu 23.10 and it seems fan1_input  Operation not supported. I observed 1 fan did spin during booting up in kernel 6.2 with Ubuntu 23.04.
$ uname -a
Linux skynet 6.5.0-26-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar  5 21:19:28 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -c video 
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 81
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
   resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:139 memory:4080000000-40ffffffff memory:99400000-9943ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
X11

$ dkms status amdgpu
amdgpu/6.1.5-1609671.22.04, 6.2.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed

$ lsb_release -r
Release:    23.10

$ sensors
gigabyte_wmi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +30.0°C  
temp2:        +36.0°C  
temp3:        +27.0°C  
temp4:        -55.0°C  
temp5:        +27.0°C  
temp6:        +31.0°C  

amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:         N/A
edge:         +47.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)


/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2$ cat fan1_enable
1

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2$ cat fan1_input
cat: fan1_input: Operation not supported

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2$ cat  fan1_target
cat: fan1_target: Operation not supported

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2$ cat pwm1_enable
1


$ sudo pwmconfig
   hwmon0 is acpitz
   hwmon1 is nvme
   hwmon2 is amdgpu
   hwmon3 is coretemp
   hwmon4 is gigabyte_wmi
   hwmon5 is iwlwifi_1

Testing pwm control hwmon2/pwm1 ...
cat: hwmon2/fan1_input: Operation not supported
  hwmon2/fan1_input ... speed was  now 
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: line 455: let: threshold=3*/4: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/4")
    It appears that fan hwmon2/fan1_input
    is controlled by pwm hwmon2/pwm1
cat: hwmon2/fan1_input: Operation not supported
    Fan hwmon2/fan1_input has not returned to speed, please investigate!

$ systemctl status fancontrol

fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; preset: e>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-04-03 10:43:23 EDT; 3min>
   Duration: 63ms
       Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
             man:pwmconfig(8)
    Process: 1118 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/fancontrol --check (code=exited, statu>
    Process: 1351 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fancontrol (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

I tried fancontrol, fan2go, but ends with the same error to read fan1_input. Switching the fans has the same outcome. Even the one used to work on ubuntu 23.04 doesn't work at all on 23.10 now.
Does this mean the fans are bad or gpu is bad? I suspect 1 fan is. How can I make the fan run based on its temperature? Thanks.

Either both fans or the cable is bad. Replaced the whole set and new fans start spining from boot-up in both windows 10 and ubuntu.
